# How to generate continuing indices for multiple objects in nested arrays that are in an array

Tags: json, jq, unique-id

Given

```
[{
  "objects": [{
    "key": "value"
  },{
    "key": "value"
  }]
}, {
  "objects": [{
    "key": "value"
  }, {
    "key": "value"
  }]
}]
```

How do I generate

```
[{
  "objects": [{
    "id": 0,
    "key": "value"
  },{
    "id": 1,
    "key": "value"
  }]
}, {
  "objects": [{
    "id": 2,
    "key": "value"
  }, {
    "id": 3,
    "key": "value"
  }]
}]
```

Using jq?

I tried to use this one, but `id`s are all `0`:

```
jq '[(-1) as $i | .[] | {objects: [.objects[] | {id: ($i + 1 as $i | $i), key}]}]'
```

Comment: Show what you have attempted to do first?

Comment: @Morgoth Added. But I feel it might be fundamentally wrong.

Comment: That's fine if it is. People are more willing to help if they can see that you are trying :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to a simple solution here is to break the problem down into easy pieces. This can be accomplished by defining a helper function, `addId/1`.  Once that is done, the rest is straightforward:

```
# starting at start, add {id: ID} to each object in the input array 
def addId(start):
  reduce .[] as $o
    ([];
     length as $l 
     | .[length] = ($o | (.id = start + $l)));

reduce .[] as $o
  ( {start: -1, answer: []};
    (.start + 1) as $next
    | .answer += [$o | (.objects |= addId($next))]
    | .start += ($o.objects | length) )
| .answer
```

Comment: Thank you, it works! And inspired by your solution, I came up with a slightly different one. Added as another answer, but I will accept your answer.

Comment: Thanks, @hgl.  I didn't use foreach as it requires jq 1.5 or later, whereas `reduce` was an early bird.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by @peak answer, I came up with this solution. Not much difference, just shorter way to generate IDs and opt for `foreach` instead of `reduce` since there is intermediate result involved.

```
def addIdsStartWith($start):
    [to_entries | map((.value.id = .key + $start) | .value)];

[foreach .[] as $set (
    {start: 0};
    .set = $set |
        .start as $start | .set.objects |= addIdsStartWith($start) |
        .start += ($set.objects | length);
    .set
)]
```